# Problem converting curl to python with cert and key

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

i am trying to convert this curl to python:

```
curl --cert cert.pem --key key.pem https://....
```

my python code looks like that:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://...',cert=('cert.pem', 'key.pem')
```

it does not matter if i set `verify` to `True` or `False`. The curl command works, but the python code returns an access denied message and Response [403]. Can someone help me, thanks

cert.pem is the certificate and key is an rsa private key.

Is there maybe a way to do it with pycurl instead of requests?

Comment: How did you get this curl command ? From inspect section in network tab ?

Comment: There is a really nice online tool I have been using for this. https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: Ya it's good tool but sometimes it doesn't give correct output in python's case. I have faced issues while passing json in it. They show data=data as an output instead it should be json=data. @BorislavStoilov

Comment: @BorislavStoilov the online tool cannot handle --key and --cert

Comment: @BenLeitzbach: Is your key encrypted?

Comment: @anon_143 it is an api request where you have to verify with the certificate and a private rsa key

Comment: @l'L'l the key looks like -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----....-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: Have you tried adding verify= "Path of cert.pem " ?

Comment: i tried it, but then i get a SSLError "bad handshake" @anon_143

Comment: It is very difficult to say then. I guess you have to dig more. Sorry. It may depend on urls as well. Ideally it should have worked by your method.

Comment: Post your entire `curl` and `python` commands,

Comment: the url does not matter for the request. Beside that the commands are complete @l'L'l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a problem with the `requests` library and a used the `http.client` and `ssl` libraries instead.

```
import http.client
import ssl
certificate_file = 'cert.pem'
certificate_secret = '.key.pem'
host = 'url.com'

request_url = '/api/call..'

context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=certificate_file, keyfile=certificate_secret)

connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection(host, port=443, context=context)

connection.request(method="GET", url=request_url)

response = connection.getresponse()
print(response.status, response.reason)
data = response.read()
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the key file as it should be already embedded in the `.pem` file.

Just do `r = requests.get('https://...', verify='cert.pem')`

Comment: i also tried that and i get the response ´(Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))´

Comment: Check if the certificates are valid https://2.python-requests.org/en/v1.1.0/user/advanced/